# Some what simple script. Can see what's wrong

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Here is the link to the page with the script.
http://signsourceak.com/index1.html

Here is my script and for some reasons all the functions fire with out mouse over. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my script

```
window.onload = sliding;
var tags = new Array('tag1','tag2','tag3','tag4','tag5','tag6','tag7','tag8');// List of headings
var pics = new Array('popout1','popout2','popout3','popout4','popout5','popout6','popout7','popout8');// list of images that slide out

function sliding(){ // assing event 
    for(var i=0; i< tags.length; i++){
        document.getElementById(tags[i]).onmouseover = slideout(tags[i],pics[i]); // <-- The Problem is Here Function runs with out the actual event
        document.getElementById(tags[i]).onmouseout = slidein(tags[i],pics[i]);
    //alert('this worked,'+ tags[i] + pics[i]);
    }
}

function slideout(hid,picid){
    document.images[picid].style.visibility = "visible";
    document.images[picid].style.MozOpacity = 0.7;// need browser compatability
    moveout(hid,picid);
}

function moveout(hid,picid){
    if(currpos(picid) > 0){
        document.images[picid].style.top = currpos(picid) - 1 + "px";
        setTimeout(moveout,10);
    }else{
        clearTimeout(moveout);
    }

    function currpos(element){
        return document.getElementById(element).offsetTop;
    }
}

function slidein(hid,picid){
    document.images[picid].style.MozOpacity = 0.5;// need browser compatability
    movein(hid,picid);
}

function movein(hid,picid){
    if(currpos(picid) < 210){
        document.images[picid].style.top = currpos(picid) + 1 + "px";
        setTimeout(movein,10);
    }else{
        clearTimeout(movein);
        document.images[picid].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    function currpos(element){
        return document.getElementById(element).offsetTop;
    }
}
```

Comment: use 4 spaces before each line your code to highlight it in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the result of slideout() and slidein() as the handlers. You also need to isolate the closure variables; self calling functions will  make sure the the i looping variable is not shared by all the event handlers

```
function sliding(){ // assing event 
    for(var i=0; i< tags.length; i++){

        document.getElementById(tags[i]).onmouseover =(function(index){
            return function() {
               slideout(tags[index],pics[index]);
            }
        })(i); 

        document.getElementById(tags[i]).onmouseout = (function(index){
            return function() {
                slidein(tags[index],pics[index]);
            }
        })(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ross: When you have a function defined inside another function, the inner function has access to the variables defined in the outer function. The closure is what keeps those variables around, so they can still be accessed after the outer function finishes running. In your original example, the `i` variable is kept in a closure. Part of the bug was the fact that by the time the handlers (inner functions) was called, i was set to tags.length, and that's the value that was used in the handler.

Answer (score 1):

that is not how to use clearTimeOut.

setTimeout returns a timer id that have to be passed to clearTimeOut:

```
var timer = setTimeout( fn, 10 );
clearTimeout( timer);
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is here:

```
function sliding(){ // assing event 
    for(var i=0; i< tags.length; i++){
        document.getElementById(tags[i]).onmouseover = slideout(tags[i],pics[i]); // <-- The Problem is Here Function runs with out the actual event
        document.getElementById(tags[i]).onmouseout = slidein(tags[i],pics[i]);
    //alert('this worked,'+ tags[i] + pics[i]);
    }
}
```

In that loop, you're **calling** the "slideout" and "slidein" functions, though it's obvious that that's not what you want to do.  What you **want** is to assign a function that calls "slideout" or "slidein" the appropriate way. To do that, you'll need another layer of function:

```
function makeHandlers(index) {
  return {
    'out': function() { slideout(tags[index], pics[index]; },
    'in': function() { slidein(tags[index], pics[index]; }
  };
}

function sliding() {
  for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; ++i) {
    var handlers = makeHandlers(i), tag = document.getElementById(tags[i]);
    tag.onmouseover = handlers.in;
    tag.onmouseout = handlers.out;
  }
}
```

As @BiAiB notes, your calls to "setTimeout" and "clearTimeout" need some attention too.